# How to combine multiple expect conditions in protractor?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I have a protractor-jasmine test where I am trying to check that all the fields on the page are blank. I wrote a simple test using for loop that works. Now, my problem is that I am trying to adhere to protractor/jasmine best practices which say to have only one test per expect conditions. How do I change this code to only one expect conditions?

Here is the test I wrote:

```
it("should check that all input fields are blank", function() {
    allInputs.then(function(elements) {
        elements.forEach(function(element){
            expect(element.getText()).toEqual("");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Short: You can just do this - `expect(allInputs.getText()).toEqual("")`.

More Details: `element.all().getText()` returns an array containing the text values of all the child elements and since you are expecting the values to be blank, Just check if the total string is blank.

To answer you generic question of

> "How do we handle a scenario when we have need multiple validations to
>   be performed"

Expected Conditions provide conditional options - like OR, AND etc. Refer the [official documentation here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions)

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var titleContainsFoo = EC.titleContains('Foo');
var titleIsNotFooBar = EC.not(EC.titleIs('FooBar'));
// Waits for title to contain 'Foo', but is not 'FooBar'
browser.wait(EC.and(titleContainsFoo, titleIsNotFooBar), 5000);
```

In case you would like to group multiple expects

```
Promise.all[
expect(allInputs.getText()).toEqual(""),
expect(allOutputs.getText()).toEqual("")
].then(function(){
   done();
  })
```

UPDATE 1: `Promise.all` syntax above was incorrect. It should be `Promise.all([Array of Promises])` where I had the curled braces missing.

This is the correct way of doing it

```
describe('Describe something', function() {
    it('check check', function(done) {
        browser.get('http://www.protractortest.org/#/')
        Promise.all([
            expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('protractortest'),
            expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('org')]).then(function() {
            done();
        }).catch(function() {
            done.fail('somehow the Url is incorrect');
        })
        browser.sleep(10000)
    });
});
```

This gives us the flexibility to group all the validations in a test case into a single Promise(provide all promises returned by expects in an Array). This will help us group all the assertions and Pass/Fail the test case and throw a custom error message for all the set of Validations

UPDATE 2: As I mentioned above. `element.all().getText()` returns an array and to compare, I incorrectly compared an Array object to String object.We need to do a `array.join()` and compare

```
 allInputs.getText().then(function(values){
    expect(values.join('')).toEqual('')
})
```

Comment: Thanks! This answer atleast 2 of my concepts, maybe more :) I have 2 questions though. Why do we need to put in a wait in the second code block you provided? Secondly, in which case do we need the last code sample?

Comment: Regarding this question - `Why do we need to put in a wait in the second code block you provided?` - I just picked taht example from Protractor tutorial .but you dont need to do that. And for next question - ` Secondly, in which case do we need the last code sample?` .. I use this code when a test case really needs multiple expects .. What I do is .. I group all the promises returned by different expects under a Promise.all() and pass the test case only of they all resolve to success

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Promise.all seems like a good way but still the test will contain multiple expects. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Also, `expect(allInputs.getText()).toEqual("")` is not working for me. I am getting the following error: `Expected [ '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '' ] to equal ''`

Comment: Promise.all code block is not working..It gives the following error: `Failed: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Comment: @Ravi ... sure .. gimme some time ... will look into it ... i typed the reply from mobile and there could be some typos

Comment: @Ravi ... Sorry .. their was a typo in `Promise.all` and I have updated the question with both answers ..check if that works

Comment: I tried Promise.all. Test passes but gives the following warning : `(node:13340) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): ReferenceError: done is not defined`